# question regarding epoll: where exactly is stored? can it be accessed? how? what happens if a socket drops?

Tags: node.js, epoll

I have a server I want to retrieve all the requests from the epoll but I'm kinda new to this. so can anyone please tell me if that is possible and if yes, where is the data stored? how long is the data stored? or is it destructive like select? is it reliable in case of the sockets going dead? is epoll accessable through node js framework to do such task(getting/reading all the requests)?

is there any other way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could explain more on your scenario.

I belive you are working on a very high demanding server. In the mean time take a look at this, let me know if it is on any help

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9csgxBgaZ8&ab_channel=node.js
2. [Understanding libuv / epoll / non-blocking network IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578964/understanding-libuv-epoll-non-blocking-network-io)

Comment: thank you for the response.the scenario is a little abstract for me as well here is what I have so far I hope it helps:I have an actor model implemented on a cluster of nodejs frameworks. these actors carry out lists of requests and execute them. if the nodejs framework crashes I want all the requests from the epoll to be retrieved because I want the new actors to continue executing the remaining requests that failed to be executed.